# Why doesn't Robin appear in the Justice League and Justice League Unlimited animated series?

Tags: character, dc-animated-universe, justice-league-unlimited, justice-league-tv

Robin is part of the [DC animated universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe), so why doesn't he appear in the [Justice League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_%28TV_series%29) or the follow-up [Justice League Unlimited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited) series?  What is the reason behind not including any Robin or Nightwing character in the Justice League series; not even as a special appearance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [**IMDb**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0275137/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv):

> When the series was expanded from Justice League to Justice League Unlimited, producers considered adding Batman's sidekicks, *Robin*, *Batgirl*, and *Nightwing*.
>
> However, DC Comics turned them down, because **the *Robin/Dick Grayson* role was being used on** [***Teen Titans***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans_%28TV_series%29).

---

There was/is something called **["(Bat)-Embargo"](http://www.worldsfinestonline.com/WF/sections/faq/)**:

> a decision to keep certain DC characters exclusive to certain shows across the television and film medium.

**Bruce Timm**, the man behind *Justice League* and *Justice League Unlimited* [said about the *Bat-Embargo*](http://jl.toonzone.net/004/004.htm):

> *... to tell you the truth, as much as I […] love those characters, I don’t really miss [them] all that much.  It’s not like we don’t have tons of other interesting characters to play with.*
>
> *If I were doing an actual Batman show, and not allowed to use those characters, yeah, that’d be pretty galling, but **Batman’s only one ingredient in the Justice League’s brew.  The Bat-clan aren’t really essential in any way to the current show** ...*

- [although](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Batgirl#Trivia),

  > At one point during the later series *Justice League Unlimited*, **an episode featuring *Batgirl* was discussed**. ... The episode was never produced as the rights to the Batgirl character were not held over and were being used by the team on *[The Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_%28TV_series%29)* at the time

However, in the episode [Grudge Match](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Grudge_Match) they sidestepped the *Bat-Embargo*:

> *Dick Grayson* has a blink-and-you-miss-it cameo as *Nightwing*, shown watching from a rooftop as *Canary* and *Huntress* drive their way into Blüdhaven.
>
> [image: Nightwing]
>
> - [Watch the scene on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6cVOIVLc_8)

Comment: +1 for nice detailed answer. I previously knew this Nightwing scene but i didn't recognized him that time.

Comment: When I saw that Nightwing clip for the first time I was hoping he would make more of an appearance in the episode.

Answer (score 5):

At the time Warner Bros., owners of DC Comics and makers of these shows, had a newly-successful [Batman film franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_begins).  As a result, they [essentially reserved](http://dcanimated.wikia.com/wiki/Bat-embargo) the Batman "universe" (i.e. his settings, friends, and foes) for those films and for [Batman-specific TV series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_%28TV_series%29).  The end result was that both the *Justice League* series and *Smallville* couldn't make extensive use of Batman, Gotham, Robin, Nightwing, etc.  Other Justice League members didn't have such a limitation, and so the series saw significant use of their rogues galleries.

Comment: But justice league used batman,gotham(not sure but i think they used it),joker,cadmus and many more batman properties.

Comment: Clayface ,Copperhead,Harley Quinn,Clock King etc. Not sure if deadshot can be counted or not.

Comment: Don't forget Terry McGinnis(batman) and alferd.  I f i am not wrong there are few more batman related character but not remember at the moment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7915/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-keen)

Answer (score 3):

Blüdhaven appears briefly in the Justice League Unlimited television series episode "Grudge Match" as the backdrop for a meta-human fighting match organized by Roulette in which female Leaguers under mind control (including Fire, Wonder Woman and Black Canary) fight it out. A signboard at the city's entrance says "Welcome to Blüdhaven". In the same scene, the silhouette of Nightwing appears in a cameo. (Source:[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bl%C3%BCdhaven#Television))

Answer (score 2):

People don't actually notice but dick grayson and barbara gordon ARE in Justice league 1'st season in the season finale. It's a single minute but if you catch it in the right second. It's when flash, lantern, and wonderwomen are in an alternate reality and Batman is a vigilante rebel against Savages army. Among batmans soldiers you see a couple right before they kiss. A long haired man that resembles Dick and a red headed women resembling Barbara. That isn't a coincidence. You also notice a boy that looks like tim drake and a girl that looks like annie the daughter of clayface. Amazing

Comment: Could you provide an image of the scene you're talking about?

Comment: Alternative time lines, don't really count here imho, but +1 for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget that joker is not in JLU either. The reason neither he nor Tim appears is because by the second series, the whole Joker Junior plot unfurled, which forced Batman to dismiss Tim. This part is confusing because the flashback scene was made before either JL series so Bats was still in his TNBA costume. But judging by Joker appearing in season 2 of JL as well as season 1, he kidnapped Drake by the end of JL and died before JLU