# Why does DCAU avoid the Speed Force?

Tags: character, production, dc-animated-universe

[Speed Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_Force) is an essential part of Flash mythos. Yet in [DC Animated Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe) (DCAU) they avoided it to a major extent. Flash doesn't even have lightning effect when he runs and Speed Force wasn't named except in ***Justice League Unlimited S02E12 "Divided We Fall"***, and didn't get referred to again.

I know the reason for avoiding a few of Batmanlore stuff was due to **(Bat)-Embargo** which was discussed [in my other question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/10472/1190).

But what was the reason for avoiding reference to Speed Force? Is there some kind of Flash-Embargo too? Is there any official confirmation of this decision?